# Реализация тестовых вопросов Java SWING

Tags: java, swing, gui

Не могу понять, как реализовать тесты закрытого типа с одним вариантом ответов (radiobutton). Не знаю, как реализовать переход от одного вопроса ко второму. 
Пример (просто для понимания что мне нужно):

**Вопрос 1**:
ответ 1
ответ 2
ответ 3
ответ 4.
кнопка ОК.

и вот что бы при нажатии кнопки ОК, мне в этом же окне,предыдущий вопрос заменился на следующий вопрос и следующие 4 варианта ответа.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Размещаете текстовое поле или `JLabel` с вопросом и группу радиокнопок с вариантами ответов. У них всех есть свойство `Text` (его можно установить через `setText` или `setLabel`).

> setText(String text) Defines the single line of text this component
>   will display.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html

Такой же метод (setText(String text)) для JRadiobutton: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JRadioButton.html

2. После того, как пользователь сделает выбор радиокнопки - у неё изменится свойство на `selected = true`. (`setSelected()` вызываем мы сами при событии нажатия на радиокнопку.)

[Здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) есть подробный мануал по каждому типу элементов управления (кнопок разных типов, в том числе и радиокнопок).

3. По нажатии на кнопку ОК Ваша задача считать какая радиокнопка `isSelected` или `selected/checked == true`.
4. После принятия ответа - назначьте новые тексты для их `label/text` свойств. Если радиокнопок много или мало - добавьте новые на форму или скройте (или удалите, но лучше скройте).
5. Повторяйте, пока не кончатся вопросы теста.

Пример с `JRadioButton`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/RadioButtonDemoProject/src/components/RadioButtonDemo.java

Более простой пример: http://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/jradiobutton-basic-tutorial-and-examples